# Problems with Yeoman webapp generator

Tags: web-applications, terminal, gruntjs, yeoman

I have a problem with yeoman, i recently reinstall yeoman and the generator-webapp (https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp).

But now, when i start `yo webapp` in terminal and i tried to answer first questions, it doesn't accept my answers and always return me `Invalid input`

example :

> [?] Would you like to include Twitter Bootstrap for Sass? (Y/n) n
>
> > error:   Invalid input

i tried to uninstall node.js and all packages et reinstall it but it doesn't work either. If anybody have an idea of what happens and how i can solve this.

I have tried with others generators and it works fine.

Thank you !

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. This issue has been logged at the generator-webapp repo:

https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/issues/81

Comment: The issue is fixed in the latest release.

Comment: Are you in windows? If you are, did you try other than cmd? like powershell.